# Solspace Calendar: ICS import field mapping

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, calendar

Is there any way to import additional fields from ICS files via Solspace Calendar (v1.8.13 on EE v2.10.1).  There are the default Calendar: Events fields which typically get populated with imported data.  And I can add additional fields like for links and images to the field group, but is there a way to map imported data into these additional fields?

I didn't see anything in the documentation or in the Calendar module in the CP to address this.

Answer (score 0):

At this current time there is no officially supported way to do this with ICS Update.

Comment: I did notice that in the iCalcreator.class.php, it does grab the URL from the ICS file.  In some quick testing, I was able to map that data to a new custom link field in act.calendar.php.  Was there a reason why this wasn't included?